# Copy Data from one cell and insert them to another cell under a unique word or sentence

Tags: insert, cell, spreadsheet

You will find two columns in the below link. Columns A and B. I want to insert the data in Columns A2 to Cell B2 under this line 'Critical Dates Meeting Comments:'
[Dates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1caaAuQQvSuwdcWp_LXQ4mDLI8tlgSqUEk5XZxJbpeLc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet102");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet102");
  sheet.getRange("A2:A164").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("B2:B164"));
}
```

I used the code but it only transfer the data from A to replace B.
Is there a way to alter this code or maybe use another one to insert data instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. It is a Regexreplace formula instead of an appscript.

```
=REGEXREPLACE("name of the Cell you want to paste the string into","(.*KEYWORD)","$1"& char(10)& " " & "Name of the cell you want to transfer the string from")
```

- KEYWORD is defined as after which unique word you want the word to be
  pasted.
  the " " is just to push the word a space to align under the keyword. Not necessary if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the app script, please find the solution to this problem here in a more detailed way.

- The data in the given range of column A (A2:A164) is being copied to an array.
- Then loop through the array in order and copy the relevant data with the custom prefix ('Critical Dates Meeting Comments:') to the corresponding cell in the B column.
- Remove the respective data from column A. `cellA.setValue("");` - This line can be removed in the code if you do not want the data to be removed from column A.

The code for this problem is as follows,

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeA = sheet.getRange("A2:A164"); // Get range of column A
  var valuesA = rangeA.getValues(); // Get values in column A
  for (var i = 0; i < valuesA.length; i++) {
    var valueA = valuesA[i][0];
    if (valueA !== "") {
      var valueB = "Critical Dates Meeting Comments:" + "\n" + valueA; // Append small text to value in column A
      var cellA = rangeA.getCell(i+1, 1);
      var cellB = cellA.offset(0, 1);
      cellB.setValue(valueB); // Set value in column B
      cellA.setValue(""); // Clear value in column A
    }
  }
}
```